# PocoDynamo Scan Item count with expression

Tags: servicestack

I need to count the number of records based on a criteria. The ScanItemCount doesn't take a filter expression, so I wanted to explore the best way for getting the total number of records.

Below is a code sample that I have used to get the count. Is there a better alternative to this? Also if there are 10,000 records for a given customer in the db, then would the query return the exact count or I have to use LastEvaluatedKey to iterate through the result.

```
 var total = (long)_dbConn.Scan<int>(new ScanRequest(DynamoMetadata.GetTable<T>().Name) {
            FilterExpression = "#col = :val",
            ExpressionAttributeNames = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "#col", "CustomerId" } },
            ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> { { ":val", new AttributeValue(CustomerId.ToString()) } },
        }, (Func<ScanResponse, IEnumerable<int>>)(r => (IEnumerable<int>)new int[1]
        {
            r.Count
        })).Sum();
```

Also I would like to avoid returning all the columns but instead a scalar result.